# Intersection of list in the old way: without sets and without in operator

Tags: python, intersection

As a python user, it is quite an unusual question. For once, I can not use all the magic functions and lovely build-in operators. Thus I am kind of lost.

I have 2 to 6 lists containing lists of custom objects. The objects do have a method `__eq__` but it is actually not correct for this usecase. Moreover, they are loaded from a pickle file. Thus, I can not modify the object class and re-implement the method.

```
L1 = [[Obj1_1, Obj1_2, Obj1_3], [Obj2_1, Obj2_2, Obj2_3], ...]
L2 = [[Obj1_12, Obj1_21, Obj1_33], [Obj2_1, Obj2_2, Obj2_3], ...]
...
```

As stated in the title, I'm looking for the element of L1 presents in all the other lists. i.e. I'm looking for the sublist of objects present in the other lists of sublists.

**How to I define if a list of object from L1 is the same as a list of object from L2:**

```
List_of_Obj_in_L1 == List_of_Obj_in_L12 and [elt.s for elt in List_of_Obj_in_L1] == [elt.s for elt in List_of_Obj_in_L2]
```

Knowing those lists are quite large (thousands of elements), how can I find the intersection based on this condition?

**Dummy example:**

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, f, s):
        self.f = f
        self.s = s

    def __eq__(self, D):
         return self.f == D.f

    def __ne__(self, D):
         return not self.__eq__(self, D)

L1 = [[Dummy(f, 0) for f in  (20, 30, 20, 50)], [Dummy(f, 0) for f in  (20, 30, 20, 40)], [Dummy(f, k) for k, f in  enumerate((20, 30, 20, 50))], [Dummy(f, 10) for f in  (20, 50)]]

L2 = [[Dummy(f, 0) for f in  (20, 20, 20, 50)], [Dummy(f, 0) for f in  (10, 10, 10, 10)], [Dummy(f, k) for k, f in  enumerate((20, 30, 20, 50))], [Dummy(f, 10) for f in  (20, 50)]]
```

The intersection would be those 2 lists:

```
Intersect = [[Dummy(f, k) for k, f in  enumerate((20, 30, 20, 50))], [Dummy(f, 0) for f in  (20, 50)]]
```

Now this example has only 2 lists, L1 and L2. What if I have L1, L2, L3, L4, L5 and L6 and I want the elements present in ALL of them?

I'm currently trying using for loops, and an equality function:

```
def equality(L_dummy1, L_dummy2):
    if L_dummy1 == L_dummy2 and [elt.s for elt in L.dummy1] == [elt.s for elt in L.dummy2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

intersection = list()
for elt in L1:

    in_L2  = False
    for elt2 in L2:
        if equality(elt, elt2):
            in_L2 = True

    in_L3 = False
    for elt2 in L3:
        if equality(elt, elt2):
            in_L3 = True

    if in_L2 and in_L3:
        intersection.append(elt)
```

Any better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: first, why don't you break once you set your flags to True? the rest of the loop won't do anything useful...

Comment: Consider implementing a wrapper class that holds one of these objects, and implements the desired `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` semantics for them.  Make one pass generating wrapped versions of all the data, then you can use normal set operations on them.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed, dummy example written a bit fast, break should be placed.

Comment: @jasonharper Smart. I do know how to implement the `__eq__()` however I do not know much about hashtable and the implementation of the `__hash__()` method.

Comment: Long story short: take the XOR (`^`) of the `hash()` of all the fields that your `__eq__()` will be comparing, or at least a large enough subset of the fields such that their combination is likely to be unique.  You may have to go a bit deeper if any of these are lists or other unhashable objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly shorten it, using `all` and `any`:

```
def equality(L_dummy1, L_dummy2):
    return  L_dummy1 == L_dummy2 and \
            all(elt1.s==elt2.s for elt1, elt2 in zip(L.dummy1, L.dummy2))

intersection = [
    elt for elt in L1 if all(any(equality(elt, x) for x in l) for l in (L2, L3))
]
```

In both the `equality` and the intersection the use of `all` and `any` guarantees early breaking of the iterations. There is no need to build the full lists of `elt.s` if you know they are not equal when you see the first mismatch.